# AWS - migrar wordpress de una instancia a otra

Tags: wordpress, aws

Tengo una instancia WordPress Certified by Bitnami con una tienda en woocomerce que tenia un problema al mandar los correos de las ventas/compras realizadas, el error era por que la fecha y la hora en la instancia estaba desincronizada y para corregirlo seguí las instrucciones de este articulo

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Me conecte vía SSH para efectuar las configuraciones cuando mi consola se congelo en el proceso de instalación de **chrony** por lo que tuve que reiniciar la instancia y esta se daño a nivel sistema operativo.

Ya intente crear una instancia de recuperación y montar como volumen secundario el disco de la instancia dañada y de esta manera puedo acceder a los archivos de la instancia dañada, **pero mi problema es que no puedo hacer funcionar mi viejo wordpress en mi nueva instancia, no se como migrarlo de manera adecuada.**

Comment: Aparte de montar tu disco de respaldo, deberás modificar convenientemente apache para que sirva el contenido de dicho disco. No tengo muy claro que actuaciones has realizado sobre tu nueva instancia, ni de que tipo es, ni que software tiene instalado. Tampoco me queda claro si estás intentando ejecutar apache desde tu disco de respaldo o una nueva versión instalada en tu nuevo EBS raíz. Lo mínimo que deberás hacer es modificar el directorio root de apache.

Answer (score 0):

**¡Solucionado!**

El SO de la instancia quedó inservible, por lo cual tuve que hacer un respaldo manual de los archivos del proyecto por medio de una instancia de recuperación, así como los archivos de la base de datos del Wordpress.

1. Monte una nueva instancia donde subí el mi proyecto en un nuevo Wordpress
2. Recupere la base de datos del Wordpress a partir de los archivos frm y ibd
3. Restaure la base de datos en la nueva instancia del proyecto